# Extension not working in Chrome 24

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use the following lines to define `BlobBuilder` object and `slice` function in Chrome extension

```
    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder;

Blob.prototype.slice = Blob.prototype.slice || function(start, length) {
    return this.webkitSlice(start, start + length);
}
```

It works in Chrome with version up to 23, but for the latest version 24, it does not recognize my definitions any more. For example, `var builder = new BlobBuilder()` will prompt an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlobBuilder` webkit version `WebKitBlobBuilder`  is no longer supported by Chrome and is deprecated, Check [this issue](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/115666)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info, but what should I do to fix this? Can I somehow enable WebKitBlobBuilder in my extension files or replace it with something else?

Comment: @chaohuang: As per resolved status in Chrome 24 i don't think you can enable it, may be you can try in older versions of chrome.